# Why is union sign not allowed to denote intervals of function increasing?

Tags: notation

On the calculus exam, we were given a function $$f(x) = \frac{2x^2+x-1}{x^2-1}
$$ and asked to find intervals of function increasing and decreasing. In the post-exam solutions PDF, it was written that f(x) is increasing on $$(-\infty; -1), (-1; 1), (1; +\infty)$$
And specifically noted that writing the function increase interval as $$(-\infty; -1) \cup (-1; 1) \cup (1; +\infty)$$ is wrong and unacceptable, however, I fail to understand why so.

**So, why is union-sign notation incorrect?**

Comment: Increasing on the union requires the function to be increasing across the discontinuities of the domain.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: that should have been an answer :)

Comment: I'd say that the point is that the union of intervals fails to be an **interval** and the question is specifically asking for intervals.

Comment: There are several correct answers here. My comment is to suggest that the formulation you ask about causes unnecessary trouble by trying to use symbols rather than words to describe the answer. Reserve formal mathematical notation for the places where it is really called for.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The function is decreasing (not increasing, as you said)  on each of those three intervals separately. But it is not decreasing on their union because, for example, $f(5)>f(0)$.

Consider a similar case: my bank balance is decreasing from December 9 through December 14, and from December 16 through December 21. Is it therefore decreasing on the entire interval? No, because on December 15 I received my salary, so my bank balance increased sharply between December 14 and 16.

Answer (score 9):

<s>I have never seen one write an interval like $(a;b)$. The standard notation is $(a,b)$.</s>

Consider a simpler example: $g(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$. Note that $g$ is increasing on the interval $(-\infty,0)$ and also increasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$. However, $g$ is **not** increasing on the *set* 
$$
S=(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty).
$$

Comment: Note: where decimal separator is comma (not dot), it's good to write intervals as $(a;b)$, especially with numbers. $(1,2,3)$ is ambiguous while $(1,2;3)$ or $(1;2,3)$ is not.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Indeed. Now I have seen it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma  Thanks for pointing that out! And pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Often another spacing is used as well, as in $(1{,}2;3)$ and $(1;2{,}3)$.

Answer (score 9):

## Introduction

So, we are considering the function $f$ defined by

$$f(x) = \frac{2x^2+x-1}{x^2-1}.$$

Clearly, this function is defined everywhere except at $x = \pm 1$, so its domain is $D_f = \mathbf{R} \setminus \{-1, +1\}.$

Let us draw its graph, just so we can see very clearly what is going on:

[image: The graph of the function in the question]

Now, we are interested in knowing where the function is *decreasing*. Obviously, to answer this question, we need to know exactly what the word "decreasing" means in this context.

## What does the word mean?

Likely your calculus textbook contains a definition very similar to this one:

*A function $f : D_f \to \mathbf{R}$ is *decreasing* on the set $U \subset D_f$ if, for all $x, y \in U$, it holds that $x < y \Rightarrow f(x) \ge f(y)$.*

So, fundamentally, the concept of "decreasing" applies not to a function alone -- or to a function at a particular point --, but to a function and a subset of its domain ($U$ in the definition above). For instance, it is meaningless to say that "$f$ is decreasing at $x = 5$" [you do not have two points to compare<sup>1</sup>!], but it makes sense to say that "$f$ is decreasing on $(-3, -2)$". (And that would be true in our case.)

## Let's apply the definition

Now it is easy to see that our function $f$ is indeed decreasing on each of the subsets $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1, 1)$, and $(1, \infty)$. For example, if you pick any two numbers $x$ and $y$ in $(-1, 1)$, it is obvious that if $x < y$, then $f(x) \ge f(y)$.

Notice how beautifully the precise definition captures the essence of our intuitive idea of what it means to be "decreasing"!<sup>2</sup>

But with this precise knowledge, it also becomes very easy for us to see why $f$ isn't decreasing on $(-\infty, -1) \cup (-1, 1) \cup (1, \infty) = \mathbf{R} \setminus \{-1, +1\} = D_f$.

Think about it for a while.

For example, take $x = -2$ and $y = 2$. Clearly $x < y$, but $f(x) \ge f(y)$ **doesn't** hold. [Intuitively: when we moved to the right, the value of the function *increased*!]

So it is very much not the case that $f$ is decreasing on $D_f$.

## A small note on terminology

If the exam question asked for "the *intervals* where the function is decreasing", you should probably answer it by giving one or more intervals -- and not sets that aren't intervals. But the union clearly isn't an interval, so this also makes it obvious that that answer is incorrect.

[For example, there are no two real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that

$$\mathbf{R} \setminus \{-1, +1\} = (a, b)$$

so the union clearly isn't a bounded open interval.]

## A subtle difference

A different exam question could have asked you to find the points in $D_f$ where the function's derivative is non-positive. This is a related but different question. The derivative of a function is also a function, and it has a value at each point where it is defined. So in contrast to the discussion above, it *does* make sense to say that the derivative of $f$ is non-positive at the particular point $x = 5$, say.

If you compute the derivative of $f$, you find a function $f'$ that is also defined on $D_f$. And its value is non-positive (even negative) everywhere. So it is true that the derivative is non-positive in each of the subsets $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1, 1)$, and $(1, \infty)$. But this immediately implies that the derivative is non-positive in their union $D_f$.

Consequently, this hypothetical exam question could (indeed, should) be answered by giving the union in its most simplified form.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Exercise (very technical): What do you have to say about the statement "$f$ is decreasing on $\{5\}$"?

<sup>2</sup> Yeah, this is one of the reasons why I love mathematics. And the $\epsilon\delta$ definitions in calculus ... Beautiful.

Comment: (+1) Your effort to explain the answer in details and also explaining related material is incredible. However you should note that sometimes people would look for the most simple answer rather than the most detailed answer (even though the latter provides a better point of view on this mathematical area in general).  To save your time I suggest you don't read what's not written in the question. The OP asks specifically about the difference in notations and it seems that he already understand the definition of increasing/decreasing function (or at least he don't ask about it).

Comment: @Yanko: It is hard to tell exactly what the OP understands and what (s)he doesn't fully understand. Still, I think it is good if a Q contains several answers with different approaches and levels of detail. Plus, I have all the time in the world! :)

Comment: Yes it's hard to tell what the OP understand. In fact sometimes detailed answers are well received and useful. This time I'm afraid that the OP is unlikely to read your answer but it might come in handy for other users. Anyway if you continue provide such answers and with "all the time in the world" you have I'm sure you'll become a great contributor for this site.

Comment: And the geometric interpretation of the formula $x<y\Rightarrow f(x)\ge g(y)$ is the following. Whenever you pick two distinct points from the graph of $f$ within the domain in which we consider whether $f$ is decreasing, then the leftmost one of the two points (let us call it $(x,f(x))$) is located _higher_ (in ordinate) than the rightmost one ($(y,f(y))$). In other words, if you pick the two distinct points on the graph, the secant passing through them has a negative (or zero) slope. If you pick points from _different_ branches in your image, it is not hard to get a positive secant slope.

Answer (score 5):

Because $(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$ is *not* an interval.

Comment: For the same equation, for concavity intervals, the answer was given using union-sign notation though. I just don't understand why writing like this would be considered incorrect.

Comment: I believe that I provide an answer to that question.

Comment: But it might be reasonable to say $\dfrac{x^3-x}{x^2-1}$ is increasing on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$

Comment: But the question was about finding *intervals* in which the function is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers have focused on the fact that $f$ is not increasing from one interval to the next.  An even better example would be $g(x)$ defined as $-1/x$ when $x<0$ and $\sqrt{x}$ when $x\ge 0$.  Then $g$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0);[0,\infty)$.  But we definitely can't say that $g$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0)\cup[0,\infty)=(-\infty,\infty)$.